# Drush bootstraps fine via root, but fails via regular account (SSH, dedicated server)

Tags: drush

I hope someone here can help me out on this one: After pushing our site live, I am now trying to get Drush running on our live server. I have gone for a manual install via our root account, got the library and dependencies inside the `/usr/local/lib/drush`, a symlink at `/usr/bin/drush` and made sure that execution rights are set for both root and the regular account.

on the regular account (a.k.a. *not-root* account), tasks like downloading a module work fine, it puts the module into the correct directory and everything, but commands that require a database connection fail with this notice:

```
[error] Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
[error] The drush command 'en metatags' could not be executed.
[error] Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
```

**However**, executing commands like `pm-enable` via the **root** account work perfectly fine!

Doing a `drush -v status` does not result in any errors, but (unlike via the root account) it does not yield in a successful database connection.

I attempted to run the `mysql` command manually with the same host/username/pass as set in the settings.php, and that worked perfectly fine.
I have tried forcing 127.0.0.1 as host as suggested by the link in the outputted notice, but obviously no luck, as the mysql socket seems to be fine.
Execution rights on `mysql` and `php-cli` are available and the `php.ini` file is readable from the main account.

**Conclusion/Assumption:** 
Because the root account is having no issues but the regular account does, I *assume* the issue boils down to missing execution and/or reading rights. But – if that is the case – for which file?

The reason I don't want to handle our drupal installation from the root account is not only would that likely mess up file permissions and ownership (modules downloaded via root will be owned by root?), but also I would simply feel more comfortable working via an account that does not have the abilities to nuke the entire server.

Some further details on the setup:
- PHP OS: Linux
- Drush version: 7.0-dev
- Drupal version: 7.27
- PHP version: 5.5.11

I hope someone here can point me towards the right direction of solving this issue. Any form of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you take a look at the permissions of '.drush'? `ls -l ~/.drush`

Comment: @Wtower thanks for your comment! i just checked `~/.drush` from my regular account and it is owned by that very account with full permissions: drwxr-xr-x, same for the `cache` folder and subfolders